# Can I match a character string containing m-d with a date vector in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

All, Ive seen that date conversion questions get downvoted a lot, but I couldn't find any information online or in the help files...

I have a df with a date formatted as ymd_hm() and then some data in other columns. Then I have another df with 366 row, one for each day, and a column containing some values relevant for that day (some climatological stuff, that is essentially the same every year, so the year doesn't matter). The dfs might look something like this:

`df1 <- tibble(Date=seq(ymd_hm('2010-05-01 00:00'),ymd_hm('2010-05-03 00:00'), by = 'hour'), Data=c(1:length(Date)))`

`df2 <- tibble(MonthDay=c("04-30", "05-01", "05-02","05-03","05-04"), OtherData=c(20,30,40,50, 60))`

Now, is it possible to do some lookup sort of thing and match `Date` and `MonthDay` and then write whatever `OtherData` is into `df1`? I'm struggling since I can't convert `MonthDay` to a date. 
So, all the 2010-05-01 dates should have 30 next to them, all 2010-05-02 dates should have 40 in the next column, and so on and so forth...

Thanks y'all!

Comment: Try `df1 %>% mutate(MonthDay = format(Date, "%m-%d")) %>% left_join(df2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We extract the 'MondayDay' with `format`, use that as common joining column in `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(MonthDay = format(Date, "%m-%d")) %>%
     left_join(df2) %>%
     select(-MonthDay)
```

Comment: Ah, I had played with format before, but tried it on MonthDay... Thank you!